# Is it possible to make PHP exceptions non-fatal?

Tags: php, exception, xdebug

I wrote a class whose methods frequently throw a number of Exceptions--for example, a `NoResultException` if the given user ID doesn't correspond to a user, a `BadTokenException` if the token was wrong, an `EmailTakenException` if the e-mail address is already registered, etc.

I am trying to write a test program using it really quick. I was feeling lazy and I didn't want to write `try/catch` blocks. I probably will now, but I still have to ask: is it possible to change PHP's behavior and make it so that Exceptions don't produce fatal errors? In other words, can I make my script catch the Exceptions and output them using the default exception handler (since I'm using XDebug and the backtrace is nice), but allow the script to finish executing? Then I can just see the message of the error (like "The e-mail address is already taken") without stopping the rest of the page from being printed.

Thanks.

Comment: [set_exception_handler](http://www.php.net/set_exception_handler) maybe?

Comment: Well, I will write them in production. I'm just asking if it's possible to treat exceptions like non-fatal errors and continue execution, so that when I'm testing I can just have it print the exception and backtrace but continue the program. I'm guessing it's not. The reason why I can't use `set_exception_handler` is (a) there is no `get_exception_handler` so I can preserve and call XDebug's backtrace, and (b) there is no way to make `set_exception_handler` not terminate script execution immediately after it fires.

Comment: Don't abuse exceptions and you won't have this problem. Exceptions are for exceptional cases your examples really are not and are not what exceptions should be used for.

Comment: Should I have a function return false and another function return the last error? What about a constructor case, where you can't have a return value?

Answer (score 2):

use `trigger_error` instead. it throws non-fatal errors

```
trigger_error("Custom Error", E_USER_ERROR);
```

display it via `set_error_handler()`

see
https://www.php.net/trigger_error

and
https://www.php.net/set_error_handler

Comment: But then I would need to rewrite the class again for production, because errors aren't catchable....

Answer (score 0):

You can only make exceptions non-fatal if you catch them through try/catch blocks and you've just said that you're too lazy to do that? This makes no sense. You either use trigger_error or you add try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have uncaught exceptions be non-fatal by creating an set_exception_handler function to handle them. Most of the time I just show a HTTP 500 system error page. If there is a way to recover (Which I'm not sure why you wouldn't do it in a try/catch) you can do there by looking at the Exception class and the error code number in the exception.